# MYSQL: why is the following update trigger not working?

Tags: mysql, triggers, mariadb

```
CREATE TRIGGER `add_history` AFTER UPDATE ON `meters`
FOR EACH ROW 
 CASE inserted.id
 WHEN 2 THEN
   INSERT INTO waterlog SET deciliter = 5;
 WHEN 3 THEN
   INSERT INTO eleklog SET kwh = 1;
END CASE
```

Depending on the row that is updated ( a record with id 2 or 3),i want to run a different query.
meters table looks like

```
id   meter   value
2        water    121
3        elek     344
```

value is regularly updated and need to trigger the creating of a log entry in another table.

Comment: Your `insert into` syntax is false

Comment: strange, when the trigger is changed to CREATE TRIGGER `add_history` AFTER UPDATE ON `meters`
FOR EACH ROW 
   INSERT INTO waterlog SET deciliter = 5 , it works, same insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `add_history` AFTER UPDATE ON `meters`
FOR EACH ROW 

IF (NEW.id = 2) THEN
    INSERT INTO waterlog SET deciliter = 5;
ELSEIF (NEW.id = 3) THEN
    INSERT INTO eleklog SET kwh = 1;
ENDIF
```